# C++ Overload index operator for more than one array/vector

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

I'm not an advanced programmer. How can I overload the `[]` operator for a class that has two (or more) array/vector type variables?

```
class X
{
protected:
    std::vector<double> m_x, m_y;
public:
    double& operator[](const short &i) { return ???; }
};
```

What should I use for `???`, or how can I do it (maybe adding other definitions?) to be able to call either variable?
Additional question: will this allow other classes of type `class derived : public X` access `m_x` and `m_y` for writing?

---

UPDATE:

Thank you everyone who answered, but I'm afraid that if I draw the line then the answer to my first question is no, and to the second yes. The longer version implies either an extra `struct`, or `class`, or plain setters/getters, which I wanted to avoid by using a simple function for all.
As it stands, the current solution is a (temporary) reference to each variable, in each class to avoid the extra `X::` typing (and keep code clear), since `m_x` would have existed, one way or another.

Comment: Why you do not use `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` instead of two separate vector?

Comment: One method, one variable. Try to give us more information about the semantic of your code. Moreover the additional answer is *yes*.

Comment: @sorosh_sabz What do I do if I have more than two vectors? #Biagio It's an interface class that holds variables common to all the classes that access the variables. Their number is undefined, i.e. it will grow in time.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen If your dimensions will grow statically in time, you can increase depth of the vectors. Or you can use [composition pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/composite-pattern.html) with create one dimensional leaf.

Comment: @sorosh_sabz That is not a concern, in fact, the vectors are chosen as vectors, not arrays, because they have variable sizes. It's just that accessing is a bit cumbersome, so, not knowing too much at this point, I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 0):

you can write just a function for this, like:

```
double &get(unsigned int whichVector, unsigned int index)
{
   return (whichVector == 0 ? m_x[index] : m_y[index]);
}
```

or use operator():

```
    struct A
    {
        std::vector<int> a1;
        std::vector<int> a2;

        int operator()(int vec, int index)
        {
            return (vec == 0 ? a1[index] : a2[index]);
        }
    };
    A a;
    auto var = a(0, 1);
```

but still, this is kinda strange :) probably you should just give a const ref outside, like:

```
const std::vector<double> &getX() const { return m_x; }
```

and second question: protected will be convert into private in public inheritance (child/derived will have access to these memebers)

Answer (score 0):

You can return a struct has two double

```
struct A{
 double& x;
 double& y;
 A(A& r) : x(r.x), y(r.y){}
 A(double& x, double& y) : x(x), y(y){}
};


class X
{
protected:
    std::vector<double> m_x, m_y;
public:
    A operator[](const short &i) { 
      A result(m_x[i], m_y[i]);
      return result;
    }
};
```

Thank for editing to @marcinj

Comment: You can use std::pair<double, double> instead of write new class

Comment: @sorosh_sabz he said two or more variable. Can I do std::pair<double, double, double> with std::pair ?

Comment: `std::tuple` obviously.

Comment: @burakozgul You can use `std::tuple` instead of `std::pair` if you want represent more than two element.

Comment: I like the solution with proxy A class (in client code you ratain naming of variables : x and y), the problem is that it returns temporary so it is not possible to modify m_x and m_y, more codding is needed in this solution.

Answer (score 0):

If using mixin doesn't make you uncomfortable you could use tag dispatching like:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <size_t I>
struct IndexedVector {
   std::vector<double> v;
   IndexedVector():v(10){}
};

template <size_t I>
struct tag {
   int i;
};

template <size_t S, class = std::make_index_sequence<S>>
struct MixinVector;

template <size_t S, size_t... Is>
struct MixinVector<S, std::index_sequence<Is...>>: IndexedVector<Is>... {
   template <size_t I>
   double &operator[](tag<I> i) {
       return IndexedVector<I>::v[i.i];
   }
};

int main() {
   MixinVector<2> mv;
   mv[tag<0>{0}] = 1.0;
   std::cout << mv[tag<0>{0}] << std::endl;
}
```

To use `std::index_sequence` you need however compiler supporting c++14 (you could though implement it yourself in c++11). The approach is easily expandable to any number of vectors by simple `MixinVector` template parameter modification.

Comment: It doesn't look bad, but it seems like a painted version of a getter(x,i). And all the answers so far, though each bringing up their valid points, just make the code too fluffy, which is what I was trying to avoid in the first place. It's a pity about the overloading, but I may resort to using `X::m_x` and so on, maybe a pointer or a reference as a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want `m_x` and `m_y` indexed against the same parameter and a single return value:

```
struct XGetter
{
   double& x;
   double& y;
};

XGetter operator[](const short &i) { return { m_x[i], m_y[i] }; }
```

And the `const` overload:

```
struct XGetterReadOnly
{
   double x;
   double y;
};

XGetterReadOnly operator[](const short &i) const { return { m_x[i], m_y[i] }; }
```

The compiler will make a good job of optimizing away the intermediate classes `XGetter` and `XGetterReadOnly` where appropriate which maybe hard to get your head round if you're a new to C++.

Answer (score 0):

There are many broken things, either at conceptual and design level.

Are you able to point your finger simultaneously against two distinct things? No? That's why you cannot use one index to address two distinct vector retaining their distinction.

You can do many things: whatever way to "combine" two value int one is good
by a syntactic point of view:

`return m_x[i]+m_y[x]` or `return sin(m_x[i])*cos(m_y[i])` or `return whatever_complicated_expression_you_like_much`

But what's the meaning of that? The point is WHY THERE ARE TWO VECTOR IN YOUR CLASS? What do you want them to represent? What do you mean (semantically) indexing them both?

Something I can do to keep their distinction is

```
auto operator[](int i) const 
{ return std::make_pair(m_x[i],m_y[i]); }
```

so that you get a `std::pair<double,double>`  whose `fist` and `second` members are m_x[i] and m_y[i] respectively.

Or ... you can `return std::vector<double>{m_x[i],m_y[i]};`

---

About your other question: Yes, inheriting as public makes the new class able to access the protected parts: that's what protected is for.

And yes, you cam R/W: public,protected and private are about visibility, not readability and writeability. That's what const is about.

But again: what does your class represent? without such information we cannot establish what make sense and what not.

---

Ok, stated your comment:

you need two different funcntions: one for read (`double operator[](unsigned) const`) and one for write (`double& operator[](unsigned) const`)

If you know vectors have a known length -say 200-, that you can code an idex transforamtion like i/1000 to identify the vector and i%1000 to get the index,so that 0..199 addres the first, 1000..1199 address the second 2000..2199 address the third... etc.

Or ... you can use an `std::pair<unsigned,unsigend>` as the index (`like operator[](const std::pair<unsigned,unsigned>& i)`, using i.first to identify the vector, and i.second to index into it, and then call x[{1,10}], x[{3,30}] etc.

Or ... you can chain vetor together as

```
if(i<m_x.size()) return m_x[i]; i-=m_x:size();
if(i<m_y.size()) return m_y[i]; i-=m_y:size();
if(i<m_z.size()) return m_z[i]; i-=m_z:size();
...
```

so that you index them contiguously.

But you can get more algorithmic solution using an array of vectors instead of distinct vector variables

if you have `std::array<std::vector<double>,N> m;` instead of m_x, m_y and m_z the above code can be...

```
for(auto& v: m)
{
   if(i<v.size()) return v[i];
   i-=v.size();
}
```

Comment: There can be more than two vectors, and they represent an accumulation of data, thus variable according to calculations. These calculations are done by external derived classes, each class in its own way, for example (not real case) humidity, temperature, etc, and the number of derived classes can vary (I may add wind speed, or altitude, for ex.). And I wanted to overload `[]` for quicker read/write accessing of the variables, instead of using lengthy `Class::getX(i)` and `Class:setX(var, i)`.